# Cloud Firestore Unity SDK Converters

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

There aren't yet any samples for the newly released Cloud Firestore Unity bindings, as far as I could see, so I added this to an existing app as the world's most naive Firestore test, this being a Unity-ized version of the first example here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

I thought this would work, but get an error "Unable to create converter for type UserData".

A quick glance through the reference doesn't seem to show a way to register converters (?? between object and json?) Can anyone explain what I misunderstood?

```html
[System.Serializable]
public class UserData
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public string name;
}

// Later on after FirebaseInit, etc...

        UserData userData = new UserData
        {
            x = 5,
            y = 7,
            name = "Joe Bloggs"
        };

        var write = await 

        FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection("Users").AddAsync(userData);
```

Comment: what kind of examples were you looking for with the Firebase Unity SDK? There is a [Github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity) page with some that you may find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the best thing you can do right now is manually put this data into something that matches the `IDictionary<string, object>` interface (ex: just a plain old [C# dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)) and pass that in. This is actually also true for Realtime Database (even if you pass in RawJson, it gets converted to an `IDictionary` internally).

To keep with Stack Overflow's guidelines, your implementation may look something like this:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
data.Add("x", 5);
data.Add("y", 7);
data.Add("name", "Joe Bloggs");
await FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection("Users").AddAsync(userData);
// do cool stuff here after the upload
```

An important note right now: Firestore for games is an alpha release. It's incomplete and the API is subject to change. This also means that *you* can help drive its evolution into beta. If you were to rewrite this Stack Overflow question as a feature request [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues), you'll get it on the team's radar.

Also, keep an eye on [this repository](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity). A sample app will likely appear soon.

Finally, it's awesome that you're excited and using Firestore in its alpha state. In addition to that github issue page I linked above, you can [file bugs and feature requests here](https://firebase.google.com/support). There's also a fairly active [google group here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk) and [a slack channel here](https://firebase.community/), both monitored by Firebase engineers.

Comment: Update, sample app: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/firestore/testapp

Comment: Fantastic - that works, thanks. Looking at the sample now.

Answer (score 2):

```
   [FirestoreData]
   public class UserData
   {
     [FirestoreProperty]
     public string UserId { get; set; }
    
     [FirestoreProperty]
     public string Nickname { get; set; }
   }
```

1. Add **[FirestoreData]** attribute to your class.
2. Add **[FirestoreProperty]** attribute to all of your fields.
3. Transform your fields to **{ get; set; } properties**.